# Laravel 8 use variable in all controllers

Tags: php, laravel, controller

How can i pass data to all controllers in Laravel 8.I tried to this.

```
Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

 public function __construct()
    {
        $defaultLanguage = Language::getDefaultLanguage();
        $defaultLanguageId = $defaultLanguage->id;
        View::share('defaultLanguageId',$defaultLanguageId);
    }


}
```

But that give me

```
 Method Illuminate\View\View::share does not exist.
```

this error.

Comment: "Variable in all controllers" sounds like it should be a config variable.

Comment: If you want to share it on all views then you can di it with AppServiceProvider

Comment: @EsTeAa i tried it but it didn't work.Anyway i missed parent::__construct()

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not use session?
Why not use middleware?

Anyway, Your code is missing: `parent::__construct()` before everything

Comment: Good. consider also session (expecially for language) and middleware, well, maybe both. And mark the answer as correct, thanks :)

Comment: This answer is encouraging a bad approach and should not be accepted to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using View Composers? That's what they are there for.
Please read the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers for further reference.